# Laravel Global Route ID

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm using this routing format for my custom level views:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'customers/{customer_id}'], function(){
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'orders'], function(){
            Route::get('/', 'controllers\EndUser\Accounting\OrderController@getList');
            Route::get('/{id}', 'controllers\EndUser\Accounting\OrderController@getView');
        });
    });
```

If you notice, I'm using a global 'customer_id' and for my sub pages I use a 'id'. I need to pass the 'customer_id' to every controller and every function in the controller, what would be the cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameters to the controllers that use them.

```
<?php
class OrderController extends BaseController {
    public function getList($customer_id = false)
    {
        echo 'getList()<br />'; 
        echo 'customer id = '.$customer_id; 
    }
    public function getView($customer_id = false, $id = false)
    {
        echo 'getView()<br />'; 
        echo 'customer id = '.$customer_id.'<br />';
        echo 'id = '.$id;
    }
}
?>
```

Laravel automatically makes route parameters available to the controller functions.

Comment: Looks good Dave, I figured this was the best way, I just wanted to make sure.